# could not find or load main class when running from within eclipse

Tags: java, class, runtime-error, program-entry-point

I am trying a run a java program(which is not in eclipse) from within eclipse using

```
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java " + exec);
```

(where `exec` is the path to the file)

It throws me a *could not find or load main class*. It actually has a main class and it did compile successfully  with the following statement. any help would be appreciated

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(compiler + " " + file);
```

Comment: "*where exec is the path to the file*" can you give us example of data you are passing? Do you remember that `java` accepts `full.class.path.to.YourClass` rather then system path?

Comment: path is string "C:\\users\\test"

Comment: test.java is the file and on compilation it did create test.class in the same location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments it seems that your command should probably look like

```
java -cp c:\users test
```

so try changing your code to something like

```
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -cp c:\\users " + exec);
```

where `exec` should pass `full.package.name.of.YourClass` which in your case is most probably `test` (not `test.class` or `test.java`).

Comment: im using it on windows and it does not accept -cp option. and i did not include the extension in the path to class

Comment: Have you tried running `java -cp c:\users test` command in console? What output did you get?

Comment: it works fine in cmd, but when i try to run it from within eclipse it gives me the exception

Comment: Can you post exception you are getting?

Comment: when i try it with "java -cp c:\users test" it gives me the manual entry for java command listing all the options which can be used

Comment: im so sorry. you solution of using -cp option did work. My fault i gave the path and classname without a space. Thanks so much